# Head in the Sand - SD Masters Programs

Tags: untagged

I've seen a bunch of questions about sound design/engineering education around the board and have looked into most of the recommended schools and programs.  Sadly, most of them seem only to offer courses and curriculum that mirror the school that I went to a few years ago.

Since then I've been out working on various things in various places and I have learned a ton of stuff and developed chops I never thought I'd have.  But I feel like there is more out there, more to what we do, than I am able to learn working on my own.  I've been studying films and TV, building a library, practicing, but it seems like really slow going.

I'm looking for a more immersive kind of program focused solely on sound creation, manipulation, and design.  I hate to use the word, but I want something a little more academic.  I've got the basics down, now all I want to do is dig deeper and really figure this thing out.

The [MSc programme at the University of Edinburgh](http://sd.caad.ed.ac.uk/mscsounddesign/) looks fantastic and I'm waiting on a reply from the director, but thought I'd ask to see if you guys know of anything else that might be similar (or even better).

Many thanks.

---

UPDATE:

I've been accepted into the MSc programme and the University of Edinburgh.

Hugs and High Fives to everyone. If it wasn't for this little board I'd never even have had the idea to apply.

Thanks!

Comment: Any questions about Edinburgh in general and the uni's music dept, send them my way. I'm just finishing the Music Technology undergraduate degree. Martin Parker (head of Sound Design) is a cool guy :)

Comment: @Joe, I sent him an email last night.  I actually lived in Edinburgh for 2 years in my late teens.  I miss it dearly and would love to go back.  Do tell about the Uni though, how's it going?

Comment: I am grad of the Edinburgh Sound Design course, and so was Andrew (the founder of this site). I can highly recommend it, it's fairly intense and self-driven, and if you're looking for academic and theory (rather than just learning software) then it should be down your alley.

Comment: @The Amazing Rolo, That's good to hear. Intensity is exactly what I'm looking for. The self-directed side of it is good too, I've got a few ideas that I want to spend some serious time with. Are you British/Scottish yourself?  I'm trying to figure out if there're any bursaries I can apply for as a foreigner. 

Comment: @g.a.harry if you're on Twitter, user by the name @ntkeep has just applied for the course and he's coming from India so you could ask him re bursaries for foreigners?

Comment: @g.a.harry no, I'm French/American...it meant that I didn't have any visa problems but I didn't find any funding and had to pay for it myself with loans. Depending on where you're from there are probably awards available for post-grad study (for example I think the university of edinburgh gives scholarships to a couple of americans a year), but I think most of them are for people studying foreign policy or business or something more standard :(

Comment: @Joe, from what it looks like, they hand out bursaries, &tc. according to region, so Canada (where I'm from) is a different application process and has different options than India.
@The Amazing Rolo, I'm Scottish/Canadian, so I'm hoping I can finagle the "Home" rate.  But it might be tricky applying for canadian related bursaries if I'm planning to enter under my British passport.  We shall see...  I've got a few more questions about the program, do you guys mind doing a bit of email correspondence? g.a.harry@gmx.com

Comment: @g.a.harry I did do a lot of research and was in correspondence with Martin for a while. I've received confirmation and if all paper work goes well should head there this year. You can email me if you'd like to get a discussion going. nothingtokeep[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: Congratulations on getting accepted! Hope you enjoy it as much as I did. No doubt you will :-) 

Comment: I also went to Edinburgh uni and did the SD masters last year. I couldn't recommend it highly enough! I was a bit of a music/gear freak when I joined and didn't know much about sound design, in a way I feel it would have been better to be heavily involved in sound design when I got there-so I could specialise a bit more and have the time/experience to learn more specifics. But i learnt more there in a year than I have anywhere else and you cant beat the environment there and 24/7 studio access! The fact there is so many of us from Edinburgh on this site speaks volumes about its influence on us

Comment: Congrats,have a ball and learn lots!

Answer (score 2):

Here in Helsinki we have a masters course for - [Sound in New Media](http://mlab.taik.fi/studies/master_of_arts/sound_in_new_media/) - to my knowledge it is one of the few if not the only masters program to specialize in interactive 
sound in Europe. The course is run in English and if you are quick you can graduate in around 2 years. It is definitely more academic being a masters, and you'll be given the freedom to follow your own path as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I recently went to an open day at the NFTS, check their two year [sound design for film and television](http://www.nfts.co.uk/courses/sound-design-for-film-and-television) course. it sounded like very hands on and practical but it's an MA recognized by the Royal College of Art. Applications close on the 12th of May, and the course itself starts in January 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I graduated from Bournemouth University with a Masters there in Sound Design late 2008   I think the course has changed slightly since but there was a heavier bias towards theory than somewhere like NFTS.

http://onlineservices.bournemouth.ac.uk/Courses/Course.aspx?course=1935&name=Sound+Production+for+Film+and+Television

Theory is all well and good but practical experience is worth more than anything. If I could have I would've done NFTS course too lol had interview lined up for place but thought I'd be broke for life if I did that! :p I've heard lots of good things about it though and as it's a film school you might meet the next 'big thing' director there to carry on any colloborations with ;) dont forget networking your ass off wherever you go!

Comment: @Andy I think the Bournemouth course has stopped now because the professor has retired (a few of my Twitter buddies are Bournemouth grads) but it has maybe just changed? I'll see if any of them chime in here.

Comment: I think the course is still going. It is according to the link anyway lol May have changed slightly since I was there though..